# Dynamic creation of objects vs storing them as fields

Tags: java, performance, object

I have this loop which runs about 1,000,000 times.

```
                 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                      if(!(line.isEmpty())){

                         data = new JSONObject(line);
                         name = (String)data.get("name");
                         surname = (String)data.get("surname");
                         ar.put(name, surname);  //an array

                     }
                }
```

What are the advantages (if any) in terms of efficiency of having it like that were data,name and surname are fields compared to creating a new dynamic object at runtime

```
                 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                      if(!(line.isEmpty())){

                         JSONObject data = new JSONObject(line);
                         String name = (String)data.get("name");
                         String surname = (String)data.get("surname");
                         ar.put(name, surname); //an array

                     }
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There won't be any difference, since you've only changed the scope of the variables. Since you're not using the variables outside of the scope, the generated bytecode will be identical as well (you can try it out with `javap`).

So use the second style for clarity.

Edit: In fact if you have the variables as fields of the class, the bytecode may be different. The performance will depend on how JIT will end up with it, but it's unlikely that there are significant differences (and even then, the second way would be easier to optimize -> potentially faster).

Comment: Not even in the GC process?

Comment: You're creating the same amount of objects, so it's unlikely that the GC would be affected.

Comment: What is GC going to clean here ? you are storing them in an array so still referencing them .But still if you didn't store them GC would clean the same way in both examples .

Comment: As counter-intuitive as it sounds, the second version may even be faster with respect to micro-level details of GC (though it won't actually affect garbage collection). In some GC implementations, overwriting an existing reference to another object to point to a new one can include some additional branching which may not be necessary if you just toss away the reference and create a new one. This is _extremely_ micro-level stuff that would be unlikely to show up in any real world measurements, but it's worth noting. Reusing the same refs could be more of a pessimization than optimization.

Comment: Note that your question is totally micro-level. It won't affect GC whatsoever, as it only impacts references and not actual objects allocated by GC. Now reusing the same objects from an object pool would be a true GC-level optimization, and that could net you some performance gains. But simply reusing the same reference is fighting against the compiler for teeny handfuls of clock cycles, and may, as Kayaman noted, even harm performance. If the JIT applies single static assignment, reassigning to the same references will effectively treat them like separate variables for register alloc anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The *first approach* should perform faster, because it ***uses a single*** reference for each of your variables (data, name, surname) for every loop

While the *second approach* ***creates a new*** reference for each one in every loop. So you end up creating a million references of each!!

Yet creating a reference is a constant time operation which shouldn't bother you. You should focus on making your code readable and clean. So since best practices suggest that the scope of your variables is as small as possible, I'd only go for the first approach if I knew that this method would run many times. (I mean you can wait some ms longer if its only gonna run once)

**Performance Tip:** Since you are concerned about performance, and given that you roughly know the number of iterations, I suggest you **initialize the capacity** of your `Map`

Comment: References are not created at runtime. Your answer is completely wrong except for the part about initial capacity.